# Guice can't find implementation for implicit dependencies in integration test

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I'm implementing integratin test for controller in scala play application. My base test controller is:

```
trait BaseControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneServerPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

val userRepo: AuthUserRepo = app.injector.instanceOf[AuthUserRepoImpl]
val authRouting: AuthRouting = app.injector.instanceOf[AuthRoutingImpl]
val authApiAction: AuthenticatedApiAction = app.injector.instanceOf[AuthenticatedApiAction]
val authUserAction: AuthenticatedUserAction = app.injector.instanceOf[AuthenticatedUserAction]
val fakePassThroughRefiner = new ActionRefiner[UserRequest, UserRequest] {
override protected def refine[A](request: UserRequest[A]): Future[Either[Result, UserRequest[A]]] =
  Future.successful(Right(request))

override protected def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
}


def withUser(user: AuthUser)(test: => Unit): Unit = {
  when(mockAuth0Service.validateJwt(any(), any())(any()))
    .thenReturn(Success(JwtClaim()))
  when(authUserAction.forPermission(any()))
    .thenReturn(fakePassThroughRefiner)
  when(authUserAction.forRole(Some(SystemRole.Admin)))
    .thenReturn(fakePassThroughRefiner)
test
}

protected def buildGuiceApplication(): Application = configureGuiceApplication().build()

override implicit lazy val app: Application = buildGuiceApplication()


implicit lazy val xc: XComponents = XComponents(Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("test.conf")), authUserAction, authApiAction)

def configureGuiceApplication(): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
val testConf = ConfigFactory.load("test.conf")
val configuration = Configuration(
  testConf)
new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .configure(configuration)
}
}
```

I'm trying to implement integration test for HomeController:

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(val cc: ControllerComponents,
                           pdfGenerator: PdfGenerator,
                           authUserAction: AuthenticatedUserAction)(
  implicit xc: XComponents) extends XController(cc) {

def test = withPermission(Permission.Dashboard_Read, None) (
  implicit request => {
    Ok("success ")
  }
```

)

Controller test is implemented like this:

```
class HomeControllerSpec extends BaseControllerSpec with Injecting {

"HomeController GET" should {
 "render the index page from a new instance of controller" in {

  val id = UUID.randomUUID()
  val fakeUser = AuthUser(id)

  val controller = app.injector.instanceOf[HomeController]
  withUser(fakeUser){
    val home = controller.test().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/test"))
    status(home) mustBe OK
  }

}
```

However, this results in Guice configuration error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for domain.auth.AuthUserRepo was bound.
  while locating domain.auth.AuthUserRepo
    for the 4th parameter of utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction.<init>(AuthenticatedApiAction.scala:16)
  while locating utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction

2) No implementation for utils.auth.actions.AuthRouting was bound.
  while locating utils.auth.actions.AuthRouting
    for the 2nd parameter of utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction.<init>(AuthenticatedApiAction.scala:16)
  while locating utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction

3) No implementation for utils.auth.actions.AuthRouting was bound.
  while locating utils.auth.actions.AuthRouting
    for the 2nd parameter of utils.auth.actions.PermissionRefiner.<init>(PermissionRefiner.scala:13)
  while locating utils.auth.actions.PermissionRefiner
    for the 3rd parameter of utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction.<init>(AuthenticatedApiAction.scala:16)
  while locating utils.auth.actions.AuthenticatedApiAction
```

AuthenticatedApiAction that can't be initialized looks like this:

```
class AuthenticatedApiAction @Inject()(val parser: BodyParsers.Default,
                                       authRouting: AuthRouting,
                                       permissionRefiner: PermissionRefiner,
                                       )(implicit userRepo: AuthUserRepo, auth0Service: Auth0Service, ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent]{
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me to identify the problem.

Comment: Does using `implicit val userRepo: AuthUserRepo =  ...` help? instead of `val userRepo: AuthUserRepo = ...` (same thing for all implicit required fields)

Comment: No. It doesn't. Already tried that and also tried to convert implicit arguments to regular arguments. It didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, basically I would prefer using macwire when I really have to do DI stuff, since guice does almost everything in runtime, while macwire actually will produce in compile time error if it cannot find those implicit values, I’d suggest you take a look at it to see if you can use it.

Comment: Would it be possible to autowire all needed dependencies? I've never used macwire before and now I'm keep wiring dependencies, but it keeps going deeper all the time and so far I had to add around 30 dependencies and have no idea when it will be enough to run the test.

Comment: I don't think so, the library tries to find an already defined variable in the scopes with some rules. It first looks for the variable in your current scope, then the parent classes/traits. so it needs to be defined somewhere. Although, I've not used macwire that much!

Comment: Eventually I've managed to make it work with Macwire. I had to wire many play related dependencies which looks a bit ugly at the moment, but definitely it was much easier to identify issues than with Guice. Thanks for your help. If you convert this to answer, I'll accept as correct one.